# Open databases on how doctors and their patients use technology

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm on the hunt for some open-source online data resources on healthcare services, preferably that focus on how either MDs and/or their patients perceive the use of IT tools.  I hope to find data that are exportable to Excel.

Can you provide any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific or give examples? There is US data about which providers and hospitals use certified EHR software but maybe you're asking about apps and wearables too?